# Creating flashing image on UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, nstimer, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying to create a memory game but at some point and time I want images on a UIbutton to be flashed. For x amount of seconds i want them to be visible and for x amount of seconds i want them to be hidden.  I'm stuck and would just like someone to give me an algorithm that'll work. Thanks.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823635/how-can-i-make-a-uibutton-flash-with-a-glow-or-changing-its-image-for-a-spli

Answer (score 2):

The basic approach is to pop the view in and out by setting the alpha.

```
UIView *view = imageView; // Or whatever
NSTimeInterval x = 2.0; // Or whatever

double delayInSeconds = x;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){ // Wait for x seconds to hide
    view.alpha = 0.0; // HIDE

    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){ // Wait for x seconds to show
        view.alpha = 1.0; // SHOW
    });
});
```

A slightly more visually appealing approach is to fade the image view in and out over a short duration.

```
UIView *view = imageView; // Or whatever
NSTimeInterval x = 2.0; // Or whatever
NSTimeInterval fadeInterval = 0.5; // Or whatever

double delayInSeconds = x;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){ // Wait for x seconds to hide
    [UIView animateWithDuration:fadeInterval animations:^{
        view.alpha = 0.0; // HIDE
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){ // Wait for x seconds to show
            [UIView animateWithDuration:fadeInterval animations:^{
                view.alpha = 1.0; // SHOW
            }];
        });
    }];
});
```

See [`dispatch_after(3)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_after.3.html), [`+animateWithDuration:animations:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3a), and [`+animateWithDuration:animations:completion:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a).

---

***UPDATE***

OK. based on your comment I'll make things a bit simpler.

Step 1: Make the view disappear. This can be done by setting the alpha (transparency) to 0, by setting hidden to YES, or by removing the view from it's superview. For a simple effect, this time I'll set hidden to YES.

```
view.hidden = YES;
```

Step 2: Make the view disappear after a set amount of time. There are a surprising number of ways to do this. I'll stick with dispatch_after(), but I'll make it a bit more understandable. This step has two parts. Part a) is set the time that you want the view to hid. Part b) is hide the view.

```
// Part a) Set the time you want the view to disappear.
double howLongBeforeDisappearing = 2.0; // seconds
dispatch_time_t timeToDisappear = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(howLongBeforeDisappearing * NSEC_PER_SEC));

// Part b) Hide the view
dispatch_after(timeToDisappear, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    view.hidden = YES;
});
```

There is a lot of stuff around the important code, but focus on `howLongBeforeDisappearing = 2.0` and `view.hidden = YES`. This says after 2 seconds set view.hidden to YES.

Finally, we need to reverse this to make things reappear. For this, we do the exact same thing except this time we set view.hidden to NO. Keep in mind we need to add in the time waiting for the view to disappear when setting the time to reappear.

```
// Part c) Set the time you want the view to reappear.
double howLongBeforeReappearing = howLongBeforeDisappearing + 2.0; // seconds
dispatch_time_t timeToReappear = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(howLongBeforeReappearing * NSEC_PER_SEC));

// Part d) Show the view
dispatch_after(timeToReappear, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    view.hidden = NO;
});
```

Adding this all together, we have the final chunk of code.

```
// Part a) Set the time you want the view to disappear.
double howLongBeforeDisappearing = 2.0; // seconds
dispatch_time_t timeToDisappear = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(howLongBeforeDisappearing * NSEC_PER_SEC));

// Part b) Hide the view
dispatch_after(timeToDisappear, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    view.hidden = YES;
});

// Part c) Set the time you want the view to reappear.
double howLongBeforeReappearing = howLongBeforeDisappearing + 2.0; // seconds
dispatch_time_t timeToReappear = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(howLongBeforeReappearing * NSEC_PER_SEC));

// Part d) Show the view
dispatch_after(timeToReappear, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    view.hidden = NO;
});
```

Comment: im new to objective c and dont really understand that, was thinking something more simpler that ill be able to understand also. I dont just want to put in algorithms that i dont understand. I appreciate your response and maybe when i gain more experience ill come back and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i made the buttons flash

-(void) blinkAll
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(hideBoxes) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showBoxesCurrent) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.5 target:self selector:@selector(hideBoxes) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(showBoxesCurrent) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(hideBoxes) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(showBoxesCurrent) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(hideBoxes) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.5 target:self selector:@selector(enableGamePlay) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

}

The showBoxesCurrent and hideBoxes functions are basic loops that gets all the arrays of buttons and set them to hidden or not hidden thats activated by the NSTimer function.